# Wordpress TTFB reduce

Tags: wordpress, performance, optimization, time

I try to speed up an Wordpress site, but have hard time there.

By google (https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/Server#overview) my server response should have around 200 ms. I check my server by maplatency.com and in Poland I have 7-46ms.

With clean install of Wordpress I hit around 500 ms, and there i can work on server configuration (cache modules, gzip etc).

But when I install an theme, and few plugins TTFB is around 1,40s for returning user, and hits 5s for first time load (https://www.webpagetest.org/result/180710_X5_6675abb233fe7028324a7e08e8f4f2b3/). 
I don't have installed fancy or not from good source plugins. My list is (i activate each separately to check TTFB):

- Contact Form 7 (adding about 100ms to TTFB)
- Kirki Toolkit (another 100ms)
- Crelly Slider (+200ms)
- Yoast SEO (+100ms)
- Elementor (+500ms)

1.4s TTFB for load shooolud be ok, but I am not happy about it, but 5s for first load is not an option. Customer will simply exit an site.

Is there anything I can do to lower this or should I reconcile
 with it using wordpress? ? I see articles witch said that up to 10-15 plugins for Wordpress is ok, but i cant image this right now o.O

My server: http://serwer1838036.home.pl/
My site: http://serwer1838036.home.pl/musiel/

Answer (score 1):

**4 Ways to Reduce TTFB on Your WordPress Site**

1. Utilize a Fast WordPress Host.
2. Implement a CDN.
3. WordPress Caching.
4. Use a Premium DNS Provider.

You can get more details, then you can refer link [4 Ways to Reduce TTFB on Your WordPress Site](https://kinsta.com/blog/ttfb/)